# First Load JS shared by all is rather heavy in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a project on **Next.js** framework and the problem is that First Load JS shared by all pages is rather heavy.

I want to know what possible aspects I can take into consideration to reduce it and also know if I'm doing something wrongly.

my next js version : `^10.0.3`

information relating to pages while building :
[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I would suggest installing [`@next/bundle-analyzer`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-bundle-analyzer) to get a better idea of what dependencies you're importing and which ones are contributing to that file size. This can help in identifying any unused or unnecessary libraries that could potentially be removed.

You can also look into using code splitting to reduce the bundle for the initial load of the application. This can be achieve by lazy loading code using [dynamic `import()`](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import) and/or [`next/dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import).

Furthermore, Next.js also mentions in their documentation other tools you can use to understand how much a dependency can add to your bundle.

> To reduce the amount of JavaScript sent to the browser, you can use the following tools to understand what is included inside each JavaScript bundle:
>
> - [Import Cost](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost) – Display the size of the imported package inside VSCode.
> - [Package Phobia](https://packagephobia.com/) – Find the cost of adding a new dev dependency to your project.
> - [Bundle Phobia](https://bundlephobia.com/) - Analyze how much a dependency can increase bundle sizes.
> - [Webpack Bundle Analyzer](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-bundle-analyzer) – Visualize size of webpack output files with an interactive, zoomable treemap.
> - [bundlejs](https://bundlejs.com/) - An online tool to quickly bundle & minify your projects, while viewing the compressed gzip/brotli bundle size, all running locally on your browser.
>
> — [Next.js, Going to Production, Reducing JavaScript Size](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/production-checklist#reducing-javascript-size)

Comment: I'm also having the same problem (shared first load JS files over 400KB) and tried to analyze with the suggested dev module. But the chunks displayed there do not match the one's from next build output. In addition, there are packages & components listed in bundle-analyzer which I am lazy loading (use of `dynamic` or `await import`). Is that correct? Also a lot of chunks in bundle-analyzer have encapsulated same node modules. I really think it's hard to analyze this way.

Comment: Next.js creates 2 bundles: server and client. The output from running `next build` refers to the client bundle and should accurately match the client bundle from `@next/bundle-analyzer`. Modules using dynamic import shouldn't show up in the client bundle, unless you use them in a non-dynamic way somewhere else.

Comment: Really?  Thank you for your explanation, but I am so confused. I have created another question where I have included my client analyzed bundles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66051050/nextjs-reduce-first-load-of-shared-js 
There for instance, `jspdf` is a big resource, but it is only included in one page in a function with asynchronous loading: `const {...mod} = await import('jspdf');
            const pdf = new mod.jsPDF({...});`

Comment: Not trusting the `await import('jspdf')` approach described above, I even added a `dynamic` import (next/dynamic) of the only Component that uses the ´jspdf` Module, and it is still visible in the bundle analyzer and the first load Size did not change as well.