# How to reduce unused JavaScript for next js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, next.js, pagespeed

I have a next js application where my mobile score for performance is 12. I use to have a decent score a few years back of around 65. I have upgraded from next js version 8 to 11. I have also updated my react to the latest version hoping that would improve my score a little bit but that hasn't happened to my surprise.
The worst hit is my LCP score please find the screenshot for the same below:-
[image]

My http://localhost/_next/static/chunks/pages/portal.js?ts=1629050439458 transfer size is 2,649.8 KiB attaching screenshot for the same below:-
[image]

When I had started using next js it was truly meant for production but lately, I feel I have missed out on some major updates due to which my performance has dropped drastically.

Comment: I have improved my score upto 35 for mobile by using next/script and strategically loading my scripts.

Comment: I would suggest installing [`@next/bundle-analyzer`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-bundle-analyzer) and checking what dependencies are contributing to the `pages/portal.js` size. Then, look into tree-shaking as much of those dependencies as you can.

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves will try doing this.

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [First Load JS shared by all is rather heavy in next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453801/first-load-js-shared-by-all-is-rather-heavy-in-next-js)?