# Next.js First Load JS time reduce

Tags: typescript, next.js, apollo-client

My First Load JS time of an _app page is big I want to reduce it, as I understood I can't use dynamic imports with libs, any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To be honest - not really. You are using libs that weights several kilobytes and I assume are used across whole application. Maybe you could find alternative for framer-motion that's not that big, but captcha, apollo and chakra I think are not replaceable.

Comment: And one more thing - I know that next highlights your assets as being too big (with red color), but your 183kB + page size is still really good for advance web applications. Of course try to minimize your first load, but not at the cost of everything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First Load JS shared by all is rather heavy in next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453801/first-load-js-shared-by-all-is-rather-heavy-in-next-js)