# How to reduce NextJs bundle size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, rendering

I've just created my NextJS app, and the first load bundle size is about 1.5Mb. This is my first time using Nextjs, and from what I understand 1.2Mb is incredibly massive. I've attached an image of the yarn build and also of my `package.json`.

All pages in my app query from a database, and right now the pages are rendering as static html.

I've tried all the basic stuff, such as using ES6 imports(for components rendered conditionally), but none of that is working. I believe that the issue lies in that all my pages are first fetching data from the database (if I'm wrong please correct me), however I'm not too sure how to fix that.

I know I can fetch data directly from front end using useEffect, however I don't know if that will reduce the build size.

If someone has experience with NextJs, I'd really appreciate it if they could look at my project and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks!

PACKAGE.JSON

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.3.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^13.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.5",
    "moralis-v1": "^1.11.0",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-moralis": "^1.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "web3uikit": "^0.1.159"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.35",
    "@types/react": "18.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.2",
    "typescript": "4.7.2",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Bundle:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at [First Load JS shared by all is rather heavy in next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453801/first-load-js-shared-by-all-is-rather-heavy-in-next-js) for suggestions on how to check what's contributing to that bundle size.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in _app.js. This file is shared by all other files and it's 1.03MB. So something in there is going wrong. You have to post the contents of that file to find the problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33802005)

Answer (score 1):

This likely won't be the biggest factor in your bundle size, but one easy thing to change is to switch from react to preact. It reduced the JS bundle size by ~30% for the landing page of this [Cloud GPU site](https://vedge.cloud/) that I've been working on.

Steps:

1. Install preact:

```
npm i preact
```

2. Update nextjs config:

```
const nextConfig = {
  // Put other setting here
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      Object.assign(config.resolve.alias, {
        'react': 'preact/compat',
        'react-dom/test-utils': 'preact/test-utils',
        'react-dom': 'preact/compat',
      })
    }
    return config
  },
}
module.exports = nextConfig
```

3. Build

```
npm run build # or npx next build
```

Comment: Swapping in Preact only in production builds is a very poor idea; you want you development environment to match your production as closely as possible. Switching out the underlying view library only in prod risks bugs that you may not catch before deploying. This is something we (the Preact team) have always discouraged.

Comment: @rschristian Thanks for pointing that out, I have updated to remove the `!dev` check

Comment: FWIW I know that config wasn't your own, and where it originally came from, but we weren't able to convince them to alter that (highly copied) config.

Comment: Hopefully this helps more people follow best practices for their dev environments. Thanks again for pointing out that issue :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it before running build commend `next.config.js` and putting this `output: "standalone"` into the config file.
will show on the project dir `.next/standalone` and easily reduce your NextJS bundle size.

`next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  output: "standalone",
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```