# Yahoo finance speedup in NextJS

Tags: webpack, next.js, yahoo-finance

I ran Google PageSpeed Insights on a page on my blog and got awful results, saying that it's loading in almost 6 seconds, while in reality it opens much faster.

Ideally, I'd like to have this page be statically generated, but because of the use of the yahoo-finance2 package, it is reported to be statically generated + JSON (SSG in NextJS terms).

Here is my page code

```
import yahooFinance from 'yahoo-finance2'

export async function getStaticProps() {
const stocks = [{Ticker: "AAPL"},{Ticker: "ABNB"}]
await Promise.all(
    stocks.map(async (stock) => {
        stock['prices'] = await (await yahooFinance.historical(stock.Ticker, { period1: '2019-01-01', interval: '1mo' }))
        .map((stock) => ({[stock.date.toLocaleDateString('en-us', { year:"numeric", month:"short"})]: Math.round(stock.adjClose) }))
    })
)   
return {
    props: {
        ...posts.find(post => post.slug == 'best-stocks'),
        stocks: beststocks
    }
}
```

I thought that NextJS will grab latest stock prices and generate a static page for my during the build, but it doesn't looks like this, as npm run build reports that this page relatively big (FirstJS Load is 180KB and written in yellow).

Another option I'm thinking of is to move this logic to a separate util\script file which will be executed by webpack during the site build and just output prices in plain json format that can be consumed later by the page.

Things are getting even worse as yahoo-finance2 module works only when using old files and folders layout in NextJS 13, but when I tried to move everything to layout.js, this module started to break the whole build.

I understand that NextJS 13 AppDir is still in beta, so can't blame yahoo-finance2 developer, but keeping in mind that in upcoming versions NextJS will rely on server-side generation, I'm looking for solutions that would be fully automated and fast.

Also, Turbopack is in alpha, but after facing some issues with AppDir, I don't want to try it for now, as guess it's even more unstable.

Maybe anyone already used yahoo-finance2 with NextJS 13 sucessfully?

Comment: The first step is to understand what's making the client bundle that big. See [First Load JS shared by all is rather heavy in next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453801/first-load-js-shared-by-all-is-rather-heavy-in-next-js).

Comment: Did you manage to run yahoo-finance2 inside AppDir?

Comment: nah, it's still too buggy, it didn't respect meta tags for schema org inside the body, even the latest 13.1.3, so I had to switch back to pages dir.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be not Yahoo Finance slowing down page load but rather JavaScript calculation and rendering by ChartJS. So I sacrificed sharp vector stock price charts for pre-rendered images to keep performance metrics green.